# RShiny app - rendering data table conditions

Tags: r, function, user-interface, shiny

The goal of this reactive function is to display the raw `starwars` dataset (available from the `dplyr` library) during initial testing of the RShiny app.

In current scenario, the user has to hit `Run Query` for the data to pop up at first, then can go to the filters, filter accordingly, hit `Run Query` again for the results to be displayed.

The ideal goal is for the end user to have the data pop up at first, then the user would have the ability to pick which filters they want, then hit `Run Query` for the results to be displayed accordingly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)

ui <- function(request) {
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "SW Pivot"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      actionButton("runit", "RUN QUERY"),
      hr(),
      h4(HTML("&nbsp"), "Filter Data Set"),
      
      uiOutput("hairColorFilter"),
      uiOutput("skinColorFilter")
    ),
    dashboardBody(dataTableOutput("data"))
    
  )
}

data <- starwars

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Identify Filter Choices -----------------------------------------------
  
  hairColorChoices <- sort(unique(data$hair_color))
  skinColorChoices <- sort(unique(data$skin_color))
  
  # Define User Inputs ----------------------------------------------------
  
  output$hairColorFilter <- renderUI({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        text = "Hair Color",
        icon = icon("briefcase"),
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "hairColorChoices",
          label = NULL,
          choices = hairColorChoices,
          selected = hairColorChoices
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$skinColorFilter <- renderUI({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        text = "Skin Color",
        icon = icon("thermometer-half"),
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "skinColorChoices",
          label = NULL,
          choices = skinColorChoices,
          selected = skinColorChoices
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  # Table Data --------------------------------------------------------------
  
  filterData <- reactive({
    input$runit

    isolate({
      filterData <- data %>%
        filter(
          hair_color %in% input$hairColorChoices,
          skin_color %in% input$skinColorChoices
        )
    })
  })
  
  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    filterData()
    
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a `reactiveValues` object that can be shown at the beginning.  Then `eventReactive` can create the filtered data.  Try this

```
server<-shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  # Identify Filter Choices -----------------------------------------------
  
  hairColorChoices <- sort(unique(data$hair_color))
  skinColorChoices <- sort(unique(data$skin_color))
  
  # Define User Inputs ----------------------------------------------------
  
  output$hairColorFilter <- renderUI({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        text = "Hair Color",
        icon = icon("briefcase"),
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "hairColorChoices",
          label = NULL,
          choices = hairColorChoices,
          selected = hairColorChoices
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$skinColorFilter <- renderUI({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        text = "Skin Color",
        icon = icon("thermometer-half"),
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "skinColorChoices",
          label = NULL,
          choices = skinColorChoices,
          selected = skinColorChoices
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  # Table Data --------------------------------------------------------------
  
  filterData <- eventReactive(input$runit, {
    
    isolate({
      filterData <- data %>%
        filter(
          hair_color %in% input$hairColorChoices,
          skin_color %in% input$skinColorChoices
        )
    })
  })
  
  observe({
    DF1$data <- starwars
    if (!is.null(filterData())) DF1$data <- filterData()
  })
  
  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    DF1$data
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That is awesome, thank you! Is there a way to use the 'reactive' function to create the filtered dataset?

Comment: If your goal is to update table when you click "Run Query", `event reactive` will suffice.  However, if you want to update the table whenever the user changes the selection (without clicking on RUN Query), then change the `eventReactive` to `reactive`.  Please note that filteredData is reactive.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this in place of what you have for `# Table Data`.  Don't forget the final `})` after to close the `server`. In my shiny apps I use `observeEvent` for this type of operation. Translated into words...When I press the `runit` button, I want to filter the `data` using my `input`s and then feed that data to a `DT` output.

```
observeEvent(input$runit, {
    
      filterData <- data %>%
        filter(
          hair_color %in% isolate(input$hairColorChoices),
          skin_color %in% isolate(input$skinColorChoices)
        )
    
  output$data <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(filterData)
  })

})
```